# jquery redirect on click or after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, delay, splash-screen

I have a spash screen on a website that has a div with the ID of "splash" i'm trying to make the div fade in then if the user clicks on the div it fades out and redircts to the main site. If the user dosen't click it just fades out and redirects after 10 seconds.

The timed redirect is working but not the click function.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#splash').hide();  
        $('#splash').fadeIn(1000, function() {
              $(this).delay(10000).fadeOut(1000, function() { 
               window.location = 'http://www.examle.com'; });
              $(this).click().fadeOut(1000,function() { 
               window.location = 'http://www.example.com'; });
         });
  });
</script>
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#splash').hide();
  $('#splash').click(function(){
             $(this).fadeOut(1000,function() { 
                     window.location = 'http://www.example.com'; });
             });
  $('#splash').fadeIn(1000, function() {
           window.setTimeout ( function() {
             $('#splash').fadeOut(1000, function() { 
               window.location = 'http://www.example.com'; }) }
             , 10000);
     });
 });​
```

Changes that I've made to the example:

I've moved setting the click handler outside the fadeOut function (better practice, IMHO) and I've changed your call to delay() to a setTimeout().

The difference is, delay() will not allow other jQuery code to be executed in the background, while setTimeout() will.

Comment: Thanks, the click function still doesn't work with the above code.

Comment: Sorry, the error was not what I intially thought. Try the updated code sample :)

Comment: The problem is that it's not stoping `delay()` on click. So if you click you still have to wait till the delay is over. Weird. (But it looks like you discoverd that :))

Comment: Try the updated code I posted (I edited my answer). It worked the way it was supposed to for me. Like I mentioned in my updated answer, I traded delay() which does not allow further jQuery code to execute, for setTimeout() which will.

Comment: That's also not working, It's running the fadein then the fadeout without taking the timeout into effect.

Comment: Okay. This time it works, I promise :D I've wrapped the JQuery call inside a function, which is required in this case because it's a multi-call, rather than a single function call. Interesting... I learned something new :) Again, see the code I've posted in my answer.

Comment: Thank you soo much! It did work this last time! Thanks for all  your help I hope I wasn't too annoying ;)

Comment: You're very welcome. And not at all :) I'm happy to have been able to help.